# The supremum of the difference between $f$ and a sequence of step functions

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Suppose that $(\phi_n)$ is a sequence of step functions defined on $[a,b]$ and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that
> \begin{equation*} \mathrm{sup}(|f(t)-\phi_n(t)|)\rightarrow0
> \end{equation*}
> Show that f is Riemann integrable.

I have no idea where to start, any hints would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure if it'll help, but my usual go-to would be to try to show that this makes the set of discontinuities measure 0.

Comment: First show that a step function is always Riemann integrable by examining the Riemann sums over it and showing that they must converge. Then show that the difference in Riemann sums of $f$ and $\phi_n$ must $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.